# Is there any way to synchronize caption on the Video to Youtube caption?

Tags: youtube

Currently, I add caption on original video and Youtube separately.
My Youtube video does not have voice. so I need to add caption manually for both original video and Youtube setting.
Is there any software to synchronize the caption? For example, if I add the caption on original Video, the caption is added on Youtube automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the same subtitles file locally and on YouTube as detailed on `Upload file` help on https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/edit:

> A subtitle or closed caption file contains the text of what is said in the video. It also contains time codes for when each line of text should be displayed. Some files also include position and style info, which is especially useful for deaf or hard of hearing viewers.
>
> [SEE SUPPORTED FORMATS](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698)